# QGraphicsGridLayout without effect : all components are at the same place

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qgraphicsview, pyside2

I am trying to learn PySide2 and I try to mix regular components with some of the Graphics View Framework.

The problem is that the 2 QGraphicsSimpleTextItems are displayed without regard to QGraphicsGridLayout requirements : both are at the same place (so the producted text is not readable).

here is my little, self-contained code:

```
# coding: utf-8

from PySide2 import QtCore as core, QtWidgets as wids, QtGui as gui
import sys

class Display(wids.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        wids.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.changeGraphics()

    def changeGraphics(self):
        self.resize(500, 500)

        #au top : un QWidget
        self.central_widget = wids.QWidget(self)
        self.central_layout = wids.QHBoxLayout()
        self.central_widget.setLayout(self.central_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

        self.label = wids.QLabel(self.central_widget)
        self.label.setText('Ca marche')
        self.central_layout.addWidget(self.label)

        #on ajoute le nécessaire graphique
        self.view = wids.QGraphicsView()
        self.scene = wids.QGraphicsScene()
        self.view.setScene(self.scene)
        self.central_layout.addWidget(self.view)


        #il faut disposer les éléments dans la scène par un QGraphicsGridLayout
        ##panel=conteneur général d'éléments graphiques
        panel = wids.QGraphicsWidget()
        self.scene.addItem(panel)
        layout = wids.QGraphicsGridLayout()
        panel.setLayout(layout)

        #au layout, on ajoute un élément graphique
        title0=wids.QGraphicsSimpleTextItem(panel)
        title0.setText("JEU DE MASTERMIND")
        title=wids.QGraphicsWidget(title0)
        layout.addItem(title,0,0)

        title1=wids.QGraphicsSimpleTextItem(panel)
        title1.setText("super!")
        title2=wids.QGraphicsWidget(title1)
        layout.addItem(title2,1,0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wids.QApplication(sys.argv)
    display=Display()
    display.show()
    display.changeGraphics()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

thank you.ll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore as core, QtWidgets as wids, QtGui as gui

class Display(wids.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.changeGraphics()

    def changeGraphics(self):
        self.resize(500, 500)
        #au top : un QWidget
        self.central_widget = wids.QWidget(self)
        self.central_layout = wids.QHBoxLayout()
        self.central_widget.setLayout(self.central_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

        self.label = wids.QLabel(self.central_widget)
        self.label.setText('Ca marche')
        self.central_layout.addWidget(self.label)

        #on ajoute le nécessaire graphique
        self.view  = wids.QGraphicsView()
        self.scene = wids.QGraphicsScene()
        self.view.setScene(self.scene)
        self.central_layout.addWidget(self.view)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
        self.labelTitle0 = wids.QLabel('JEU DE MASTERMIND')
        self.labelTitle1 = wids.QLabel('super!')
        self.itemLabelTitle0 = self.scene.addWidget(self.labelTitle0)
        self.itemLabelTitle1 = self.scene.addWidget(self.labelTitle1)

        layout = wids.QGraphicsGridLayout()
        layout.addItem(self.itemLabelTitle0, 0, 0)
        layout.addItem(self.itemLabelTitle1, 1, 0)

        self.panelWidget = wids.QGraphicsWidget()
        self.panelWidget.setLayout(layout)

        self.scene.addItem(self.panelWidget)        
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wids.QApplication(sys.argv)
    display = Display()
    display.show()
#    display.changeGraphics()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: ok, it's working...but I think it's very complicated, since in the QGraphicsView, the QLabels are added twice each to the scene : one time directly, and the other time indirectly : via the variables itemLabelTitlex, which are added to the QGraphicsGridLayout, which rules panelWidget's positionning, which in turn is added to the scene...

Answer (score 1):

This is not how `QGraphicsLayout` and `QGraphicsWidget` work.

This line `title=wids.QGraphicsWidget(title0)` does not embed the `QGraphicsItem` in a `QGraphicsWidget` but create a new object with `title0` as parent.

If you want to put a `QGraphicsItem` in a `QGraphicsLayout` (which is made for `QGraphicsWidget`), you have to:

- Create a new class that inherits from `QGraphicsLayoutItem` and `QGraphicsItem`.
- Implement the abstract methods

There is an example in the [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-graphicsview-basicgraphicslayouts-example.html)